# Converting SQLite to HTML?

Tags: html, sqlite

There are various utilities that allow you to convert an SQLite file to HTML format. What I am looking for is a script that would let you do this, in perl or something maybe? How would I go about finding / doing this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about dynamic generated pages? In that case just use a while loop that gets content from the database and presents them in a table.

If you just want to export it to html once, you can use export as an excel stylesheet. From excel you have the option to 'save as html'.